# AMPL: sparse syntax

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

This code piece in AMPL solves correctly the pair matching algorithm:

```
set Student;.
        # student tuples inside Student x Student
set Pair within {Student, Student}; 

       # sparse value in that tuples    
param value {Pair};

var x {Pair} binary;  # decision var

maximize total_value: sum {(i,j) in Pair} value[i,j] * x[i,j];

s.t. perfect_match {i in Student}:  # constraint
sum {(i,j) in Pair} x[i,j] + sum {(j,i) in Pair} x[j,i] = 1;

data;

set Student := A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J;

# sparse set of student tuples   
set Pair:  A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J :=  
A  -  -  -  -  -  - - - - -
B  +  -  -  -  -  - - - - -
C  +  +  -  -  -  - - - - -
D  +  +  +  -  -  - - - - -
E  +  +  +  +  -  - - - - -
F  +  +  +  +  +  - - - - -
G  +  +  +  +  +  + - - - -
H  +  +  +  +  +  + + - - -
I  +  +  +  +  +  + + + - -
J  +  +  +  +  +  + + + + -;

# sparse matrix with scores
param value:  A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J :=  
A  .  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
B  3  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
C  5  8  .  .  .  . . . . .
D  1 -4  7  .  .  . . . . .
E  2 -1  9  2  .  . . . . .
F  2  5  3  2  9  . . . . .
G  8  2  1  1  3 -2 . . . .
H  2  3  3  4  5  1 1 . . .
I 13 -1  3  4  4 -5 2 2 . .
J  1  2  6  6  7 -4 5 6 1 .;
```

This code works smoothly, but it is cumbersome because one has to declare 2 times what student tuples are valid and a value associated with that tuples.

Other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955655/sparse-matrix-in-ampl) shows an alternative syntax (showed below) for that kind of situation in an answer. The same syntax is showed in a 2011 paper from  Darin England from University of Minnesota ([Mathematical programming formulations using AMPL](http://www.isye.umn.edu/courses/ie5112/ampl/ampl_ho.pdf)) on page 5.

```
# sparse matrix with scores
param: pair: value:  A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J :=  
A  .  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
B  3  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
C  5  8  .  .  .  . . . . .
D  1 -4  7  .  .  . . . . .
E  2 -1  9  2  .  . . . . .
F  2  5  3  2  9  . . . . .
G  8  2  1  1  3 -2 . . . .
H  2  3  3  4  5  1 1 . . .
I 13 -1  3  4  4 -5 2 2 . .
J  1  2  6  6  7 -4 5 6 1 .;
```

However, its generates an error in an updated AMPL version:

```
malformed header: extra ':' (last colon)
```

Is there some solution for defining set tuples and values of set tuples in just one declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonight the AMPL support gave me a answer.

I'm quite surprised by the efficiency of AMPL support team!

> Using Windows, We found that AMPL version 20171122 and later reject
>   the user's examples with the "malformed header" message, but versions
>   20171103 and earlier accept the examples (including perfectEr.mod). We
>   have been working to fix the problem. Meanwhile, a workaround is to
>   replace "param: Pair: value: . . ." by "param: Pair: value [*,*]: . .
>   .".

I've tested it and it works in my AMPL version. I only have added `[*.*]` after `param: Pair: value` (Line 23) and before colon (`:`). Everything works smoothly.

```
reset;
set Student;
set Pair within {Student, Student}; # Student cross Student;

param value {Pair};

# Decision Variable
var x {Pair} binary;

# Objective
maximize total_value: sum {(i,j) in Pair} value[i,j] * x[i,j];

# Constraint
s.t. perfect_match {i in Student}:
sum {(i,j) in Pair} x[i,j] + sum {(j,i) in Pair} x[j,i] = 1;

data;

# Students names
set Student := A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J;  

# affinity in defined tuples (Pair)
param: Pair: value [*,*]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J :=   
A  .  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
B  3  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
C  5  8  .  .  .  . . . . .
D  1 -4  7  .  .  . . . . .
E  2 -1  9  2  .  . . . . .
F  2  5  3  2  9  . . . . .
G  8  2  1  1  3 -2 . . . .
H  2  3  3  4  5  1 1 . . .
I 13 -1  3  4  4 -5 2 2 . .
J  1  2  6  6  7 -4 5 6 1 .;

option solver CPLEX;
solve;
option omit_zero_rows 1;
display x
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some solution for defining set tuples and values of set
>   tuples in just one declaration?

The sparse version you posted works for me; initially I got an error message "pair is not a set" but this was due to a case mismatch with "Pair"; once I fixed that, it did exactly what it ought. I couldn't reproduce the error you mention. Complete working code:

```
set Student;
        # student tuples inside Student x Student
set Pair within {Student, Student}; 

       # sparse value in that tuples    
param value {Pair};

data;

set Student := A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J;

param: Pair: value:  A  B  C  D  E  F G H I J :=  
A  .  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
B  3  .  .  .  .  . . . . .
C  5  8  .  .  .  . . . . .
D  1 -4  7  .  .  . . . . .
E  2 -1  9  2  .  . . . . .
F  2  5  3  2  9  . . . . .
G  8  2  1  1  3 -2 . . . .
H  2  3  3  4  5  1 1 . . .
I 13 -1  3  4  4 -5 2 2 . .
J  1  2  6  6  7 -4 5 6 1 .;
```

(using AMPL 3.1.0.201510231950 if that makes a difference)

Other options for sparse data input:

```
param: pair: value :=
A B 3
A C 5
B C 8
...
;
```

Alternately:

```
param: pair: value :=
[A,*]
B 3
C 5
D 1
...
J 1
[B,*]
C 8
D -4
...
J 2
...
;
```

I never did figure out whether it's possible to do it in a 2-D table layout like the code you posted; that would be more readable for small data sets but I mostly work with large ones.

You can also eliminate the duplication of students by declaring Pair as a set of pairs, and then defining Student as the set of all values that appear as either member of a tuple in Pair:

```
set Pair dimen 2;
param Value{Pair};

set Students := setof{(i,j) in Pair} i union setof{(i,j) in Pair} j;
```

Then define Pair and Value as above, and Student is derived from Pair.

Comment: Yes, explicit tuple listing works and it's smart define Students indirectly. I understand that 2D syntax just fit small problems, but it's intriguing that a paper shows a syntax that simply does not work

Comment: I've sent this syntax issue for AMPL support they have answered 2 times, but I think that just now that have understood my doubt.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum I didn't test the version you posted before writing my answer, but I gave it a try this morning, and the only problem I had was with a case-sensitive set name (see edit to my answer). Once I fixed that, it seemed to work fine. So maybe it did work for the author of the paper.

Comment: Surprisingly AMPL support have answered me and gave a good syntax workaround (I've posted a answer below). My version should be more updaded than yours.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum huh, so it was a new bug in AMPL and not in the code! Interesting that nobody had reported it until now.